# Windows 10 Phone Re-Uploading Pictures already in OneDrive

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onedrive, photos, lumia-640-xl, uploading

I woke up this morning with a notification that my OneDrive was full, of which last night I had close to 2 gigabytes of free space. So, on investigating I found out that my phone was re-uploading pictures already in OneDrive, and problem is I cannot cancel the uploads when they're in the waiting queue. I tried, and I can only cancel when the upload has failed by itself.

What could be causing the problem, and how can i clear the upload queue entirely, because there's around a thousand pictures on it, and its really inconveniencing the functionality of some essential services like OneNote that I use that rely on OneDrive to sync.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the OneDrive app? Go to Settings -> About OneDrive -> Reset app.

Comment: Doesn't that actually make it worse, I mean, it ends up starting again from scratch?

Comment: In my experience it clears the upload queue and doesn't re-upload.